# How to stop echo sound for inbuilt mic in camera

Tags: html, video, webrtc

When I am try to generate video conferencing,In this video streaming is perfectly work but in audio there is generate echo sound in it.

Currently I am used webRTC api for that.
reference 
[Reference link](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/one-to-many-video-broadcasting/#meeting-roomid-8d90ouls-txu5wmi)

Comment: Can you put some code to analyze your answer.

Comment: I give link follow that

Comment: But stackoverflow is not for to Give reference link you should provide some code to identify that where is the problem.

Comment: Check this comment. https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/issues/95#issuecomment-24562690 Try to use microphone instead of built-in audio input device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to `MUTE` your video and check it will be working fine.

Code replace:

> meeting.js

`self.muted = true;
self.control = false;`